# Entity Framework with SQL Server: database contains rows in dependent table with foreign keys to rows that do not exist in principal

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework-6

I have several tables and two main tables **A** (principal) and **B** (dependent with non-nullable foreign key constraint).

I wrote a query:

```
SELECT 
    B.ID, B.ForeignKeyId, A.PrimaryKeyId
FROM 
    B
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    A ON A.PrimaryKeyId = B.ForeignKeyId
WHERE 
    A.PrimaryKeyId IS NULL
```

And got these results:

```
B.ID  B.ForeignKeyId  A.PrimaryKeyId
-------------------------------------
 11         21             NULL
 12         22             NULL
 and so on..
```

(This is fake query without any project specific data)

It looks like foreign key constraint was violated.

I use Entity Framework 6 with a database-first approach and SQL Server 12.0.

My question is: how is it possible?

I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: he will still get the results of the A Table because of the left join. Just use Inner Join to prevent the NULL Datasets.

Comment: What is your actual question?  How is what possible?

Comment: @Hubii, thanks. I know how left join works. The problem is that table B contains ForeignKeyId values that does not exist in A table  regardless of foreign key constraint.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about your question, the results you're getting are from running that query in a client (like SSMS) or you wrote some C# code that you think translates to that specific query? It's is very unlikely to be a constraint being ignored unless someone runned NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL on that table.

Comment: @AarónBC.Thanks for your answer.
This is result from running script in SSMS.
I tagged EF because all manipulation is being made using EF.
But now database contains improper data.
I didn't found any code in my project where constraint manually ignored.